# OpenSSL Boost context.use_private_key_file and context.use_rsa_private_key_file terminate program without exception

Tags: c++, c, boost, openssl, boost-asio

My code is mostly based off the boost ssl example client however I have made it completely synchronous but the example from boost will still do the same thing.

After loading the server.pem `sslContext.load_verify_file("server.pem");`

I try to load the clients key and crt for the server to verify, for the two way handshake.

```
context_.use_private_key_file("client.key",boost::asio::ssl::context_base::file_format::pem); // also tried use_rsa_private_key_file
context_.use_certificate_file("client.crt",boost::asio::ssl::context_base::file_format::pem);
```

When use_private_key_file or use_rsa_private_key_file is called a password is requested when I enter it the program terminates. Why is this? - My password is correct I have checked it with `openssl rsa -check -in client.key`

The constructor will be the only change to the boost example this is how I would use it for normal SSL handshaking.

```
    server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, unsigned short port)
        : io_service_(io_service),
                acceptor_(io_service,
                boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), port)),
                context_(boost::asio::ssl::context::sslv23)
                {
                        context_.load_verify_file("server.pem");
                        start_accept();
                }
```

For two way handshaking.

```
    server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, unsigned short port)
        : io_service_(io_service),
                acceptor_(io_service,
                boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), port)),
                context_(boost::asio::ssl::context::sslv23)
                {

                        context_.load_verify_file("server.pem");
                        context_.use_private_key_file("client.key",boost::asio::ssl::context_base::file_format::pem); // also tried use_rsa_private_key_file
                        context_.use_certificate_file("client.crt",boost::asio::ssl::context_base::file_format::pem);
                        start_accept();
                }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This failed every time when entering the password using console. However was fine when I used the callback `set_password_callback(boost::bind(&get_password, this));` it worked fine.